Largest eigenvalue of simple bidiagonal matrix
I have a square matrix, composed of identity matrix $I$, which has $-1$ above the diagonal
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & -1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
    0 & 1 & -1 & \dots &0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots &0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &\ddots & -1\\
    0 & 0 &0&0&1
    \end{bmatrix}.$$
It can be used to describe discrete isotropic derivative and I need operator norm of such object.
My question is when $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$, can I have formula for its largest eigenvalue or operator norm as a function of the size of the matrix $$\sigma(k)=?$$
When I further put A on diagonal and create block diagonal matrix
$B=diag(A, A, ..., A)$. When the number of $A$ matrices is $n$ can I have something like
$$\Sigma(k,n)=?$$
expressing operator norm of $B$ as a function of size of $A$ and number of $A$'s on diagonal? I am also interested in reasonable upper bound as I need to estimate parameter $\mu$ such that $\mu \Sigma(k,n) < 1$.

$A - I$ is nilpotent, so $1$ is the only eigenvalue for both $A$ and $B$.
